# How to sum values of selected options?

Tags: jquery, select, sum

I have 3 selectors, all selectors have some options with some values.

How do I sum all values of selected options?

```html
<select name='anch1'>
    <option value='10'>10 ++</option>
    <option value='20'>20 ++</option>
    <option value='30'>30 ++</option>
    <option value='40'>40 ++</option>
    <option value='50'>50 ++</option>
</select>

<select name='anch2'>
    <option value='10'>10 ++</option>
    <option value='20'>20 ++</option>
    <option value='30'>30 ++</option>
    <option value='40'>40 ++</option>
    <option value='50'>50 ++</option>
</select>
    
<select name='anch3'>
    <option value='10'>10 ++</option>
    <option value='20'>20 ++</option>
    <option value='30'>30 ++</option>
    <option value='40'>40 ++</option>
    <option value='50'>50 ++</option>
</select>
    
<div>SUM OF SELECTED OPTIONS</div>
```

Comment: When should the sum be calculated? Once each select has a selected option?

Comment: Please post what code you've tried so far.

Comment: how to sum values from selected options ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
$('select').change(function(){
    var sum = 0;
    $('select :selected').each(function() {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });
     $("#sum").html(sum);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8mnQR/1/

Comment: this code sum only first options , when i select other options sum dosent chnage .. .

Comment: no it doesn't ... do a jsfiddle. THis code can be run at any point, you may have to put it inside a click or blur event handler to get yr desried functinoality. But the code hsows how get all selected values and sum.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8mnQR/ - when i change options sum dosent change :( , sorry i don't know jquery , i am php programer. can you add that click or blur event ?

Answer (score 1):

```
   var sum =  parseInt($('select[name="anch1"]').val()) +parseInt($('select[name="anch2"]').val()) +parseInt($('select[name="anch3"]').val() )
```

You can do this

Comment: Never hardcode values when you can use a dynamic selector.